# Can I use a separate pre-amp in my combo amp's effects loop?

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects, effects, pre-amp

I'm curious, is it possible to use a preamp head in the effects loop of my combo amp?

The chain would be:
guitar -> combo amp in -> effects send to preamp -> preamp out to combo amp return -> power amp

Would it damage either the preamp or combo amp in such a combination?

Specifics: Can I use a Behringer Ultragain Pro Mic2200 preamp in the effects loop of a Fender Hot Rod Deluxe? (There are probably loads of tone related opinions about whether it *should* be done, but I'm just curious whether it can be done)

Comment: As long as the preamp in the loop has matching wattage and impendance you should be fine (I'm no pro, though). But why would you not just leave the combo's preamp out like this: guitar -> head preamp -> combo amp return -> cab. That way you'd only use the combo's cab, ignoring the comob's preamp.

Comment: Could you be more specific - what are the two units in question? Do you actually want to cascade the two preamps (internal and external)? What is a *"preamp head"* - is it a rack-mount preamp?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes it is a rack-mount preamp and I do want to cascade them

Comment: What make/model of combo amp and preamp?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Fender combo, Behringer preamp, but does this really matter? Like I said, I'm just curious...

Comment: It's useful to know what kinds of inputs and outputs you're talking about; for example, FX loops sometimes have level selection (for e.g pedals vs. racks) and a rack-mount preamp will likely have several different levels of output (some specifically designed to run into a guitar amp, some not). You may find reading the user manuals will cover some of these connection options.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see. It's a Fender Hot Rod Deluxe and a Behringer UltraGain Pro Mic2200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use that preamp in your combo's effects loop. The [Fender Hot Rod Deluxe](http://support.fender.com/manuals/guitar_amplifiers/Hot_Rod_Deluxe_manual.pdf) has a series (vs. parallel, so no blending for you), line-level FX loop over unbalanced connectors, which the [Behringer UltraGain MIC2200](http://www.behringer.com/assets/MIC2200_M_EN.pdf) can certainly handle. You will have to set the UltraGain to LINE (vs. MIC) mode to use the jack input.

I would start with the UltraGain's OUTPUT control in the middle position (0dB, on a range of +/-20dB), and **increase slowly at first**. It can provide a significant boost, but note that this is in-line with other boost pedals (e.g. [MXR Micro Amp](http://www.jimdunlop.com/files/manuals/M133_man_WEB.pdf) provides +26dB). You will be driving the power amp tubes harder, which will provide a different tone to overdriving the preamp (as you would with a boost before the amp's input).